# Use setTimeout to hide several elements after X seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to hide elements after the element has appeared for 2 seconds.

I am trying:

```
function hideNotif(i) {
  $('#'+i).fadeOut();
}

for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
  setTimeout(function () {
    hideNotif(i);
  }, 2000);
}
```

It only hides the first element however.

Answer (score 0):

```
function hideNotif() {
    for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
        $('#'+i).fadeOut();
}

//call like this.
setTimeout(hideNotif, 2000);
```